# Can every settings in SharePoint 2013 solely managed by script?

Tags: powershell

Due to our company policy, I need to make sure our deployment can be processed solely in script (Powershell, SQL, DOS command). No UI interaction should be involved.

I believe most of setting can be achieved with Powershell. However is there feature/settings must be setup with UI?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, so long as you aren't setting up a remote app server, you can install SP exclusively through Powershell. Here is MS's whitepaper on the subject:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262839(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262839%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Setting up the remote app server's going to require you to provide a different domain name to that server, which means you'll need to do some tweaking with it in IIS or your load balancer to make everything communicate with each other. So long as you can do that - and I have to admit my ignorance on that front - I don't see why you shouldn't be able to do even that.

Otherwise, the question here is a little bit like asking if there are any lizards in my backyard. I can tell you I can't find any no matter where I've checked but that doesn't mean they don't exist. I *can* tell you that in SP2010 I was able to set up pretty much everything from the initial config to web apps to services via Powershell, and that there have been virtually no change to the PS tools since 2010. When it comes to stuff like theming and page layouts I'd highly recommend using OOTB tools (and I count Designer as OOTB) but even then, if you *really* wanted to, you could import a file in Powershell and assign it as a master or what have you if you absolutely had to.

Comment: I am working on a migration project. Since the search method changed in SP2013, I need to replace all search-related control to new version. It is quite easy to achieve with UI but I have no idea how to script it.